# How to create custom placeholders on hook_menu, like "%node"?

Tags: routes

For example, for menus like `/node/%node`:
when `/node/1` is accessed, drupal automatically translates `1` as `node_load(1);`

I wanted to create something like `/path/%student` where, when `/path/1` is accessed, I could translate `1` into `student_load(1);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use a placeholder like %student, you need to define a `student_load()` function in your module, or an enabled module should define such function. Drupal automatically uses that function when the placeholder is used; that is the reason why you should avoid any conflict between the used placeholders and the existing functions.

In your case, you should use code similar to the following one.

```
function student_menu() {
  $items['path/%student'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'student_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('see student page'),
  );

  return $items;
}

function student_load($id) {
  // Load information from the database; return FALSE in case of error, or when the equivalent database row is not found.
}

function student_page($student) {
  // $student is the value returned from student_load().
  // …
}
```

#### Reference

- [Dynamic argument replacement (wildcard)](https://drupal.org/node/109153)
- [Wildcard usage and core's wildcards](https://drupal.org/node/209056)

Answer (score 1):

if you use hook_menu you can use

```
$items['path/%'] = array(
        'title' => '',
        'page callback' => 'my_fn',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'weight' => 0,
    );

function my_fn($student_id){
   $node = node_load($student_id);
   return $node->title;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! But this is not what I am looking for. I want the function to automatically run for when `%student` is included in the path.

Comment: I think If your link path/1 it will display the title of node number 1,or can you explain in more details